# singlePageApp control in domino 8.5.2

Tags: mobile, xpages, xpages-extlib

In Xpages I used singlePageApp " control in domino 8.5.3, If i want to develop in domino 8.5.2 means,Which control is equivalent to singlePageApp control?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should take a look at responsive web design, this allows you to hide or show specific elements in your webpage based on the size of the users browser window. 
If you do this you do not need to create a seperate page for mobile clients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The singlePageApp is part of the mobile controls in the Extension Library for 8.5.3.

There's an Extension Library for 8.5.2 too ([available in the releases section on OpenNTF](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/releases.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20Extension%20Library)), but it does not contain mobile controls.

Instead you can use the [XPages Mobile Controls project](http://mobilecontrols.openntf.org/) (but be aware that it is not maintained).

---

I will recommend that you look into upgrading the Domino server in question to the latest release.